# Why doesn't Homography draw the box over the detected object?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, sift, homography

I used this code from some OpenCV Tutorial to detect objects based on SIFT features. It works fine when using the images from the tutorial but it seems off when I used my own set of images.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

img1 = cv2.imread('img1.jpg',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('img2.jpg',0) # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks = 50)

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.3*n.distance:
        good.append(m)

if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

    h,w = img1.shape
    pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)

    img2 = cv2.polylines(img2,[np.int32(dst)],True,255,3, cv2.LINE_AA)

else:
    print("Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
    matchesMask = None

draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,0,255), # draw matches in green color
                   singlePointColor = None,
                   matchesMask = matchesMask, # draw only inliers
                   flags = 2)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,**draw_params)

#img3 = cv2.resize(img3, None, fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

cv2.imshow("Result", img3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[This is the result when I tried using the images from the tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtNKH.jpg)

[This is the result when I tried using my own image set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY6Z9.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure you did not switch query and train image the other way round during your test?

Comment: It seems like that was the problem! Thanks.